# Add triangle corner button css

Tags: css

I would to replicate this : http://prntscr.com/k5wp2t 
I try with this code, but I need help to set it better.

```
<div class="button">MAGGIORI INFORMAZIONI</div>

.button {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 120px;
 height: 50px;
 background: blue;
 }

.button:after{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 left: 30%;
 border: 30px solid transparent;
 border-bottom-color: red;
 content: "";
 }
```

thanks

Comment: Just a question: why don't you use an image for that?

Comment: I'm a neophy so I ask for advice :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it a real triangle, you need to also have color on the right side, with `border-right-color: red;`. After that, remember to make sure the triangle is the same size as the button (the button has height: 50px;, so the borders should be 25px - not 30), and position it to the right, and not 30% from the left.

```
.button {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 120px;
 height: 50px;
 background: blue;
 }

.button:after{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 right:0;
 border: 25px solid transparent;
 border-bottom-color: red;
 border-right-color: red;
 content: "";
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use this

```css
.button {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 120px;
height: 50px;
background: blue;
padding-right: 40px;
overflow: hidden;
color:#fff;
padding-left:30px;
line-height:22px;
 }

.button:after{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
height: 50px;
width: 30px;
right: -14px;
background: red;
content: "";
z-index: 1000;
transform: skew(-30deg);
 }
```

```html
<div class="button">MAGGIORI INFORMAZIONI</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this css code

```
.button {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 120px;
height: 50px;
background: blue;
padding-right: 40px;
overflow: hidden;
color:#fff;
padding-left:30px;
line-height:22px;
 }

    .button:after{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
    right: -14px;
    background: red;
    content: "";
    z-index: 1000;
    transform: skew(-30deg);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a gradient background:

```
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #F47E3E 220px,#000 0);
```

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 270px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #F47E3E 220px,#000 0);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">RICHIEDI INFORMAZIONI</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set border-left to transparent to have such a shape & move it to right as 0px.

You can also refer to this really good article on Shape using CSS here at (Shape of CSS)[https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/]

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 270px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #F47E3E;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

.button:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0px;
  border-bottom: 62px solid red;
  border-left: 62px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="button">MAGGIORI INFORMAZIONI</div>
```